# Can not start kde5

Tags: kde, opensuse

I have install my OpenSuse42.1 initially with xfce. After that I have installed KDE5 with Yast. Now I can not login, the following error message is displayed:

> Could not start kdeinit5. Check your installation.

How can I fix this issue and use kde5 on my system?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the real problem. But

zypper up

solved the problem. I assume it rerun some scripts which didn't run the last time.